# Passing variable in MYSQL select statement

Tags: mysql, bash, unix

I have a trouble with my bash script here, the mysql select to be more specific. It runs fine without a variable, but when I am declaring variable the script fails, please advise:

```
#!/bin/bash
table="user_vpn_account"
1="2" # when I introduce this variable script fails , if I will use value "2" directly script works
pwd="password"
D="database"
mysql -uroot -p$pwd -D$D  -s -N -e "SELECT port FROM user_vpn_account where user_vpn_id=$1;"
/usr/bin/mysql -uroot -p$pwd -D$D<< eof
eof
```

---

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `mysql -uroot -p$pwd -D$D  -s -N -e "SELECT port FROM user_vpn_account where user_vpn_id='$1';"` work? note that I've quoted `$1`

Comment: Can you explain the `1="2"` line? This is a syntax error as far as I know. Shell variables defined in this way cannot begin with numbers. Did you mean `set -- 2` in order to set the value of `$1` here?

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right direction  I figured it out. The issue is that  variable cant be a number so I reassigned one  aa="2" and it finally worked

Answer (score 0):

You can put $1 parameter into a variable, like this:

```
variable=$1
```

and then use it like $variable.

[Bash Guide - Variables](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html)